# Arrange three integrals in descending order

Tags: integration

Let $f(x)=(\tan x)^{\frac32} - 3\tan x + \sqrt{\tan x}$.

Consider the three integrals

$I_1=\int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx$,

$I_2=\int_{0.3}^{1.3} f(x)dx$,

$I_3=\int_{0.5}^{1.5} f(x)dx$.

Then,

$(A)$ $I_1$>$I_2$>$I_3$

$(B)$ $I_2$>$I_1$>$I_3$

$(C)$ $I_3$>$I_1$>$I_2$

$(D)$ $I_1$>$I_3$>$I_2$

which is true? Ans given D. How to approach this question? Any idea?

Comment: is there a typo in $f(x)$?

Comment: @KousikSett I have slightly edited the definition of $f(x)$ to make it clearer. Note that for the sqrt and "to the power of" you usually need curly brackets around the following item. Also you need a backslash in front of things like tan and a space after them.

Comment: [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+(tan+x)%5E(3%2F2)-3*tan(x)%2Bsqrt(tan(x)) is able to do the integral, getting $ \int \tan^{(3/2)}(x)-3 \tan(x)+\sqrt{\tan(x)} dx = 2 \sqrt{\tan(x)}+(\log(\tan(x)-\sqrt2 \sqrt{\tan(x)}+1)-\log(\tan(x)+\sqrt2 \sqrt{\tan(x)}+1)/\sqrt2+3 \log(\cos(x))+c$